# Symfony ignores / does not override values by .env.local file

Tags: php, symfony, dotenv, symfony6

Using latest Symfony 6.1 and [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#overriding-environment-values-via-env-local) says `.env.local` overrides values which are set in `.env`

This is not working for me, i.e. when the value is set in the `.env`, it is not overwritten by the value from the `.env.local`. When it is not set in `.env`, value from `.env.local` is taken into account.

Ref:

- https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#overriding-environment-values-via-env-local

Comment: In what environment did you try ? (prod/dev/test) ?
Are both files in the same directory ?

Comment: fresh instalation, dev env and yes both are in same directory... looks like @Nedvajz answer is working

Comment: You can debug with the command `bin/console debug:dotenv`

Comment: How do you get value from the env variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem lately.

I found out, that since [Symfony 5.4](https://github.com/symfony/runtime/blob/5.4/CHANGELOG.md) there was added runtime option `dotenv_overload` what is set to `false` by default.

That is set over `APP_RUNTIME_OPTIONS`, what you can update by the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/runtime.html#using-options) this way:

```
#public/index.php  
#bin/console  
  
$_SERVER['APP_RUNTIME_OPTIONS'] = [
    'dotenv_overload' => true,
];
```

Note: it is needed to update in 2 files `bin/console` for cli and `public/index.php` to enable `.env.local` overwritting.
Note2: the option `dotenv_overload` is missing for some reason in [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/runtime.html#using-options) though

Answer (score 1):

Instead of modifying `bin/console` and `public/index.php` files with:

```
$_SERVER['APP_RUNTIME_OPTIONS'] = [
    'dotenv_overload' => true,
];
```

I added the option in the composer.json:

```
{
  "require": {
    "...": "..."
  },
  "extra": {
    "runtime": {
        "dotenv_overload": true
    }
  }
}
```

Everything is explained here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/runtime.html#using-options